# pandas: iterate over multiple columns with is_monotonic_increasing

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to iterate over a time series with multiple columns and go through the columns to check if the values within the columns are motonic_increasing or decreasing.

The underlying issue is that I don't know how to iterate over the dataframe columns and treat the values as a list to allow `is_monotonic_increasing` to work.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Id          10000T   20000T
2020-04-30      0         7
2020-05-31      3         5
2020-06-30      5         6
```

and I have tried doing this:

```
trend_observation_period = new_df[-3:] #the dataset
trend = np.where((trend_observation_period.is_monotonic_increasing()==True), 'go', 'nogo')
```

which gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic_increasing'
```

I am confused because I though that np.where would iterate over the columns and read them as np arrays. I have also tried this which does not work either.

```
for i in trend_observation_period.iteritems():
    s = pd.Series(i)
    trend = np.where((s.is_monotonic_increasing()==True  | s.is_monotonic_decreasing()==True),
                     'trending', 'not_trending')
```

Comment: Think of the dataframe as a dictionary, and iterate through it. Something like this (adapt it to your code) : ``[column.is_monotonic for _, column in df.items()]`` numpy where does not iterate over the columns.

Comment: it's the first time I come across this formulation, to be honest I don't know how to include this inside of my code

Comment: no worries. I think the suggested answer is equally helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're after something which will iterate columns and test if each column is monotonic.  See if this puts you on the right track.

Per the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic_increasing.html) `.is_monotonic` is the same as `.is_monotonic_increasing`.

Example:

```
# Sample dataset setup.
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'b': [3, 2, 1, 0],
                   'c': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'd': [2, 0, 1, 0]})

# Loop through each column in the DataFrame and output if monotonic.
for c in df:
    print(f'Column: {c} I', df[c].is_monotonic)
    print(f'Column: {c} D', df[c].is_monotonic_decreasing, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
Column: a I True
Column: a D False

Column: b I False
Column: b D True

Column: c I False
Column: c D False

Column: d I False
Column: d D False
```

Comment: I swear I am sure i tried it a 1000 times! Anyways, thank you it works, I placed back the np.where and got was I was looking for!

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working.  I'm sure you tried it 1002 times ... gets all of us sometimes.  Thanks for introducing me to monotonicity!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` to apply a function to each of your columns. Since `is_monotonic_increasing` is a property of a `Series` and not a method of it, you'll need to wrap it in a function (you can use lambda for this):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'b': [1, 1, 1, 0],
                   'c': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'd': [0, 0, 0, 0]})


increasing_cols = df.apply(lambda s: s.is_monotonic_increasing)

print(increasing_cols)
a     True
b    False
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.apply` and `is_monotonic`.

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   "B":[0, 1, 0, 1], 
                   "C":[3, 5, 8, 9], 
                   "D":[1, 2, 2, 1]})

df.apply(lambda x:x.is_monotonic)

A     True
B    False
C     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```